# How does the `primary key` keyword relate to clustered indexes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, primary-key, clustered-index, physical-design

How does the PRIMARY KEY keyword relate to clustered indexes in SQL Server?

(Some people seem to want to answer this question instead of [a different question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632726/what-are-the-design-criteria-for-primary-keys), so I am giving them a better place to do so.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clustered index of a table is normally defined on the primary key columns.

This, however is not a strict requirement.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342.aspx):

> When you create a PRIMARY KEY constraint, a unique clustered index on the column or columns is automatically created if a clustered index on the table does not already exist and you do not specify a unique nonclustered index.

And:

> You can create a clustered index on a column other than primary key column if a nonclustered primary key constraint was specified.

Answer (score 9):

> How does the `PRIMARY KEY` keyword related to clustered indexes in MS SqlServer?

By default, a `PRIMARY KEY` is implemented as a clustered index. However, you can back it by an unclustered index as well (specifying `NONCLUSTERED` options to its declaration)

A clustered index is not necessarily a `PRIMARY KEY`. It can even be non-unique (in this case, a hidden column called `uniqueifier` is added to each key).

Note that a clustered index is not really an index (i. e. a projection of a table ordered differently, with the references to original records). It *is* the table itself, with the original records ordered.

When you create a clustered index, you don't really "create" anything that you can drop apart from the table. You just rearrange the table itself and change the way the records are stored.

Comment: When you create a clustered index, you do create a root index page and intermediate pages. Still +1.

Answer (score 4):

A primary key is, as the name implies, the *primary* unique identifier for a row in your table. A clustered index physically orders the data according to the index. Although SQL Server will cluster a primary key by default, there is no direct relationship between the two.