# Update Statement in ABAP not working

Tags: abap

I have an `UPDATE` statement in **ABAP** which looks like :

`UPDATE zicstt099 FROM TABLE lt_zicstt099`

The Update is failing every time with `sy-subrc eq 4`.

The database Table `ZICSTT099` has three primary keys : `WEB_USER_ID` & `EMAIL_ID` along with `MANDT` field.

I am trying to change the `EMAIL_ID` value but the same is not getting Updated.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot change primary key fields using the `UPDATE <target> FROM <wa>.` and `UPDATE <target> FROM TABLE <itab>.` statements, since they use the primary key to lookup the record(s) they must update.

Use the `UPDATE <target> SET <set1> ... WHERE ...` statement instead.

You can find the specifics over here:
https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapupdate_source.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@

Answer (score 1):

After using [UPDATE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapupdate.htm), if `sy-subrc` = 4, then at least one line was not able to be changed, either because no appropriate line was found, or because the change would generate a line that leads to double entries in the primary key or a unique secondary index in the database table.

The statement UPDATE sets `sy-dbcnt` to the number of changed lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'change' key fields in data bases.
You may delete your original entry and insert a new one with another key. But you can't change a key field. (I can't check actual, if `modify` is doing it on it's own.

If you have to change a key field, you should think about your DB-definition.

More about changing key fields:
[Can we update primary key values of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838414/can-we-update-primary-key-values-of-a-table)

Comment: This is wrong, at least in Open SQL. See the documentation quoted by René.

Answer (score -1):

hi i tried to create the table with your keys as mentioned , I advice you to use the below syntax

```
update lt_zicstt099 set email_id = 'some value' where WEB_USER_ID = 'some web id'.
```

To check if the table is updated you can use sy-dbcnt to know the number of  lines updated.
if still you face issues please comment below