# what can be used as an iterator while using prepared statement in jdbc;here I want to check if the customer exists

Tags: java, jdbc

```
             public void addCustomer(Customer customer) throws CustomerHomeException,
ClassNotFoundException {

    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:Mydb";
        String user = "user1";
        String password = "password";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        PreparedStatement smt = con
                .prepareStatement("insert into customer (ssn,customer_name) values (?,?)");
        if (this.getCustomers().equals(customer.getSocialSecurityNumber()) == false){
        smt.setString(1, customer.getSocialSecurityNumber());
        smt.setString(2, customer.getName());
        smt.executeUpdate();
        }
        smt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new CustomerHomeException("Failed to create CustomerHome", e);
    }
```

the key we use is the ssnumber ; i need to iterate through the database table and check using prepared statement

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574002/in-this-program-i-have-to-set-already-existing-value-for-ssn-in-where-clause-i

Comment: I strongly advise you to follow some JDBC, Java and SQL tutorials instead of spamming SO with each and every question you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the two approaches.

- Check the SQL state code (for unique constraint violation)

  ```
  } catch(SQLException e) {
      if(e.getSQLState().equals("23505")) // for DB2
          System.err.println("Customer already exists!");
  }
  ```
- Fire a `SELECT` first to check if the Customer exists

  ```
  ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(
   "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE ssn = " + customer.getSocialSecurityNumber());
  if(rs.next()) {
      System.err.println("Customer already exists!");
      return;
  }
  ```

**SQL State codes** *(Disclaimer: Please check your DB's documentation and verify :)*

```
 DB2        23505
 Derby      23505
 Oracle     23000
 MySQL      23000
 SQL Server 23000
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL state codes are standardized I suppose. No harm in verifying though.

Comment: I don't think the actual state code is standardized, only the "group" (the first two digits). Oracle for example does not return 2305, nor do SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're correct. Thanks for pointing this out.