# Update a database table without losing data in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have some basic questions about mobile app database management. I have searched for it but can not find answers to my questions.

Suppose that I have a **Sports** table including some sport names which will be same for every user. When a user does a sport, the workout will be added to the **Workouts** table. So, Workouts table is spesific for every user.

**1. Tables in a user's phone**

[image]
So, what if I want to add 1 more sport in Sports table and release an update? I can update Sports table in **onUpgrade** method.

**2. New version of Sports table**

[image]

**Question:** Do **Workouts** tables in **everyone's** phone change according to the new **Sports** table? (Remember that **Workouts** table is different for every user)

[image]

I know this was a really long post for this question but I wanted to explain everything. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnUpgrade` method of your SqlOpenHelper is called when you update the schema of your database not when you add more data to an existing table. I guess you could use it to version your data but to me, that seems rather a strange way to do it.

Schema changes are for example:

- Add a column to a table.
- Add a table.
- Remove a column from table.
  etc.

Whatever code you run in `OnUpgrade` will determine the structure of the database on a device.  It is all up to you.

Also, adding data to the Sports table would not affect the workouts table at all (assuming you are not using triggers)

Comment: onUpgrade method is called when DB version is changed. I am not asking it. If I make a change at Sports table and upgrade the DB version, and then release my app again, do workouts table change itself? Because there is NO way to change a table that is different at everybodies phone.

Comment: Yes that is correct. What I meant was you should change the DB version when you change the schema not when you add data.  The workouts table will only change if YOU change it.

Comment: But what is the purpose of defining the foreign key? When a Sports table's row's primary key changed, shouldn't Workout tables foreign key's change at all rows?

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking now.  A primary key is not supposed to be changed. Once set, it should always remain the same especially if you are using it in a primarykey\foreignkey relationship.  If you want to add a new row to a table, add it with a new currently unused key. Do not change all of the other keys or you will likely cause yourself no end of problems.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838414/can-we-update-primary-key-values-of-a-table

Comment: If you really REALLY must update your PK, see https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html specifically the section relating to `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: Thank you but suppose that I don't change primary keys anymore. But what if I delete a row in Sports table? In this case, how can I update Workouts table?

Comment: well when deleting a row from  Sports, you can also manually and hopefully within a transaction, delete all matching rows in Workouts OR you can see the link but this time look for  the `ON DELETE` section. https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions