# PLSQL Skip primary key violated rows

Tags: sql, plsql

[PLSQL] I want to update rows in my `Postgres` database if the updated version wouldn't violate the primary key constraint.

Assuming the table has primary keys on `col1`, `col2` and `col3` if I run a query like this:

```
UPDATE table 
  SET col2='B' 
  WHERE col2='E';
```

```
'A', 'B', 'C'
'A', 'E', 'C'
'A', 'E', 'D'
```

The query will fail and I will get a duplicate key error because of the 2nd row.

Instead I want a query that skips the 2nd row which causes PK violation and updates the 3rd row. The required table after the update query will be like the following:

```
'A', 'B', 'C'
'A', 'E', 'C'
'A', 'B', 'D'
```

Comment: PL/SQL is an Oracle product. If you are using Postgres then probably this is [Pl/pgSQL](https://postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/).

Comment: By definition, the PK is the unique identifier for a record and therefore you can’t update it. Updating it would result in a different record

Comment: @NickW, he don't want to update rows that will make conflict with primary key, the required update query should exclude all records that may conflict with the primary key.

Comment: @Ahmed you should never be updating columns that are part of a PK. You should always be doing a (delete +) insert

Comment: @NickW, I don't think so, it's not always the case, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838414/can-we-update-primary-key-values-of-a-table

Answer (score 1):

The following query will exclude all rows that may conflict with the PK:

```
update test set col2='B'
where col2='E' and (col1,col3)  not in 
(select col1,col3 from test where col2='B');
```

Check the result from [HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/npo1s49q7iazwxRYyKpN84/1).