# Rails override id on create controller with user specified id in forms in new.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

To change an id in rails
its like
Invoice.create(id: 25)
works
but in my new.html.erb, i have user specify an id (:invoiceid) and i want that id to be linked to that id.

so how do you do it?
Invocie.create(id: invoiceid) wont work.

Comment: Do u want to neste the invoice ?

Comment: If yr using devise gem or even have current_user object. Then 'current_user.invoiceid' or just for test 'User.first.invoiceid'

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even want to change primary id, please read these responses here
[link1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/should-a-primary-key-be-immutable/8320#8320)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632726/what-are-the-design-criteria-for-primary-keys), and still if you want to edit that then you will have to permit that field in strong params, like this

`params.require(:my_model).permit(:id)`